# No Schema Supplied when Completing Loop through List of URLs from File

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a web scraping project with BeautifulSoup and at one step in it I need to compile a list of links off of another list of links which I have saved to a file. The loop seems to run fine until it gets to the last line of the file, at which point it will throw an error `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?`. Full code and traceback below

Does this have to do with the fact that python is reading each row in my .txt file as a list? I also tried only having 1 for loop like

```
for link in season_links:
    response_loop = requests.get(link[0])
```

But it didn't address the error.

Here is my code:

```
Contents of file:
https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id=98&limit=10&offs=UTC
https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id=99&limit=10&offs=UTC

# for reading season links from file
season_links = []
season_links_file = codecs.open('season_links_unpag_tst2.txt', 'r')
for line in season_links_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    season_links.append(line_list)
season_links_file.close()
print('Season links file read complete' + '\n')
print(season_links)

# handling for pagination within each season
for link in season_links:
    t0 = time.time()
    for item in link: # for some reason it reads each row in my .txt as a list, so I have to loop over it again
        response_loop = requests.get(item)
        html_loop = response_loop.content
        soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')

        for p in soup_loop.find_all('p', text='›'):
            season_links.append(p.find_parent('a').get('href'))
        print('Season link: ' + item)
        response_delay = time.time() - t0
        print('Loop duration: ' + str(response_delay))
        time.sleep(4*response_delay)
        print('Sleep: ' + str(response_delay*4) + '\n')
```

Traceback

```
Season link: https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id=1&limit=10&offs=UTC
Loop duration: 2.961906909942627
Sleep: 11.847627639770508

Season link: https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/LastMatches?comp_id=103&limit=10&offs=UTC
Loop duration: 1.6234941482543945
Sleep: 6.493976593017578

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/claycrosby/Desktop/coding/projects/gambling/scraper/sb_compile_games.py", line 103, in <module>
    response_loop = requests.get(item)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 388, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
[Finished in 23.3s with exit code 1]
```

EDIT: I have tried printing each `item` and I find there's a 3rd one that comes out just called `h`. There is no whitespace or `h` in my file though

Answer (score 0):

The issue stemmed from the fact that I was trying to append to the original list from the loop. I used different lists and it processed without an error

```
# for reading season links from file
season_links_unpag = []
season_links_file = codecs.open('season_links_unpag_tst2.txt', 'r')
for line in season_links_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    season_links_unpag.append(line_list)
season_links_file.close()
print('Season links file read complete' + '\n')
print(season_links_unpag)

# handling for pagination within each season
season_links = []
for link in season_links_unpag:
    t0 = time.time()
    for item in link:
        print(item)
        response_loop = requests.get(item)
        html_loop = response_loop.content
        soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')

        for p in soup_loop.find_all('p', text='›'):
            season_links.append(p.find_parent('a').get('href'))
        print('Season link: ' + item)
        response_delay = time.time() - t0
        print('Loop duration: ' + str(response_delay))
        time.sleep(4*response_delay)
        print('Sleep: ' + str(response_delay*4) + '\n')
```